Count the difference between two received dates for specific id
I need a separate column and display count difference with previous day.
Previous day's data by received date.
Table #1:
Date       Id
---------------
8/18/2024   2
8/19/2024   3
8/20/2024   4
8/21/2024   5
8/22/2024   6

Total count 20
Table #2 - today's data:
Date       Id
--------------
8/18/2024   2
8/19/2024   3
8/20/2024   4
8/21/2024   5
8/22/2024   6
8/23/2024   2

Total count= 22
Logic as below
Date      Id        Date        Id   diff
------------------------------------------
8/18/2024   2       8/18/2024   2       0
8/19/2024   3       8/19/2024   3       0
8/20/2024   4       8/20/2024   4       0
8/21/2024   5       8/21/2024   5       0
8/22/2024   6       8/22/2024   6       0
8/23/2024   2                           2

I need to see them in single table as below:
Date      Id    Diff
----------------------
8/18/2024   2   0
8/19/2024   3   0
8/20/2024   4   0
8/21/2024   5   0
8/22/2024   6   0
8/23/2024   2   2


"I need" isn't a question. What is stopping you from doing what you need to do? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What about the content you read prior to posting this question didn't you understand?

Note that you don't even need table 1 to get the specified result. Simply return difference 0 for all dates but today.

What you, probably, need is Full Outer Join of the two tables.
The question is not quite clear, but here is how I understood it. You need to join all the rows of the two tables where either one of them could have more rows than other. The task is to calculate the difference between id column values. Since there is no instruction which table's data to subtract from and which table's data should be subtracted I used ABS() function to show the absolute difference of the two id columns.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
/* yesterday's data */
Create Table tbl_1 ( a_date Date, id Int )
Insert Into tbl_1 ( a_date, id )
           Select '2024-08-18', 2 Union All
           Select '2024-08-19', 3 Union All
           Select '2024-08-20', 4 Union All
           Select '2024-08-21', 5 Union All
           Select '2024-08-22', 6;

/* today's data */
Create Table tbl_2 (  a_date Date, id Int );
Insert Into tbl_2 ( a_date, id )
           Select '2024-08-18', 2 Union All
           Select '2024-08-19', 3 Union All
           Select '2024-08-20', 4 Union All
           Select '2024-08-21', 5 Union All
           Select '2024-08-22', 6 Union All
           Select '2024-08-23', 2;

--    S Q L : 
Select   t2.a_date as a_date_2, Coalesce(t2.id, 0) as id_2, 
         t1.a_date as a_date_1, Coalesce(t1.id, 0) as id_1, 
         ABS( Coalesce(t2.id, 0) - Coalesce(t1.id, 0) ) as diff
From     tbl_2 t2 
Full Outer Join tbl_1 t1 ON( t1.a_date = t2.a_date )
Order By Coalesce(t2.a_date, t1.a_date)

/*    R e s u l t :
a_date_2    id_2  a_date_1    id_1  diff
----------  ----  ----------  ----  ----
2024-08-18     2  2024-08-18     2     0
2024-08-19     3  2024-08-19     3     0
2024-08-20     4  2024-08-20     4     0
2024-08-21     5  2024-08-21     5     0
2024-08-22     6  2024-08-22     6     0
2024-08-23     2  null           0     2    */

See the fiddle here.
Addition:
... and if you need the aggregated result ...
WITH 
  grid as
    ( Select   t2.a_date as a_date_2, Coalesce(t2.id, 0) as id_2, 
                t1.a_date as a_date_1, Coalesce(t1.id, 0) as id_1, 
                ABS( Coalesce(t2.id, 0) - Coalesce(t1.id, 0) ) as diff
       From     tbl_2 t2 
       Full Outer Join tbl_1 t1 ON( t1.a_date = t2.a_date )
    ) 
Select Sum(id_2) as today, Sum(id_1) as yesterday, Sum(diff) as diff 
From   grid

/*
today   yesterday   diff
-----   ---------   ----
   22          20      2      */


Both tables are under the same source. Based on the received date, it will change daily, and ID is counted for it, so how do we get today's count - yesterday's count and get the difference

@David Select Sum(id_2) as today, Sum(id_1) as yesterday, Sum(diff) as diff From ( ... sbove SQL in round brackets ... );

You can UNION ALL the tables, and sum (positive) id's from table 2 and negated id's from table 1:
select a_date, sum(id) diff
from
(
  select a_date, id from tbl_2
  union all
  select a_date, -id from tbl_1
) dt
group by a_date;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/GTlSKNRh (based on @d r's fiddle, thanks!)
If you want to cheat, and know the tables always will be the same, except that table 2 has one additional, last day:
select a_date,
       case when a_date = max(a_date) over () then id else 0 end
from tbl_2


Both tables are under the same source. Based on the received date, it will change daily, and ID is counted for it, so how do we get today's count - yesterday's count and get the difference

Using one of the queries found in the answers here!
